# Grails feeds-Plugin, <pubDate> && <dc:date>, validation error

Tags: validation, grails, groovy, rss, feed

I just tried out the ***grails feeds-plugin*** http://grails.org/Feeds+Plugin

It works very easy and well, but there´s one thing I don´t understand.

As soon as I add a `publishedDate`, like:

```
     reviews.each() {
         review -> entry('fooTitle'){
             publishedDate = review.dtCreated
             review.rating + ' ' + review.comment
        }
     }
```

It generates two tags:

```
      <pubDate>Tue, 04 Sep 2012 12:10:02 GMT</pubDate>
      <dc:date>2012-09-04T12:10:02Z</dc:date>
```

The entry in Database is:

```
"dtCreated": ISODate("2013-01-15T00:52:47.0Z"),
```

but I only want the `<pubDate>` to be generated, because feed validator throws this error:

```
An item should not include both pubDate and dc:date
```

How can I solve this? I would love to use this plugin but I need a valid RSS.

Comment: is my question really that unsolveable ?

Comment: Which is the feed validator you're using?

Comment: using http://validator.w3.org/feed/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind a quick and dirty solution you can try this (it's taken from plugin's integration tests and modified):

```
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil
import groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder
import feedsplugin.FeedBuilder
import com.sun.syndication.io.SyndFeedOutput

class TestController {
private renderToString(feedType, feedVersion, Closure closure) {
    def builder = new FeedBuilder()
    builder.feed(closure)

    def type = feedType
    def version = feedVersion

    SyndFeedOutput output = new SyndFeedOutput()
    def sw = new StringWriter()
    output.output(builder.makeFeed(type, version),sw)
    sw.toString()

}

private removeDcDate(String rssFeed) {

    def dom = new XmlSlurper().parseText(rssFeed)
    dom.channel[0].item.eachWithIndex { item, i ->
        dom.channel[0].item[i].date = {}
    }

    def newResp = XmlUtil.serialize(new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind {
        mkp.declareNamespace (rdf:"http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#")
        mkp.declareNamespace (dc:"http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/")
        mkp.declareNamespace (content:"http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/")
        mkp.declareNamespace (itunes:"http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd")
        mkp.declareNamespace (taxo:"http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/taxonomy/")

        mkp.yield dom 
    })

    newResp

}

def test = {
    def articles = ['A', 'B', 'C']

     def outStr= renderToString("rss", "2.0") {
        title = 'Test feed'
        link = 'http://somewhere.com/'
        description = "This is a test feed" 

        articles.each() { article ->
            entry("Title for \$article") {
                content(type:'text/html') {
                    return "Content for \$article"
                }

                link = 'http://somewhere.com/x'

                publishedDate = new Date()

            }
        }
    }
    def cleanedFeed = removeDcDate(outStr)

    render text: cleanedFeed, contentType: "application/rss+xml", encoding: "UTF-8"

    }
}
```

Basically what it does is calling feedbuilder directly to get a string representation of the feed, then it get parsed it and the "dc:date" tags are deleted. The result is rendered as usual.

I've tested this workaround inside the plugin test suite with grails 1.3.7